# bounding the measure of some subset of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be some small number and $P > 1$. Let $I$ be an interval.
Let $X(P)$ be a set of $\gamma \in [0,1]$ with the property that
$$
|P t - \gamma | < \epsilon, 
$$
for some $t \in I$.

I would like to obtain an upper bound on measure of $X(P)$. The following is my attempt...
$$
\mbox{meas } X(P) \leq \int_{I}  \mbox{meas } ( \{ \gamma \in [0,1]: |P t - \gamma | < \epsilon  \} )  dt \leq  2 \epsilon  \mbox{ meas }I. 
$$
I feel like I am doing something wrong, because the bound doesn't depend on $P$. I would appreciate if someone could clarify what is wrong with the argument... Thank you!

Comment: If $\inf I=a$ and $\sup I=b$ then $X(P)=[0,1]\cap(Pa-\epsilon,Pb+\epsilon)$.

Comment: I thought: for each $t \in I$, we want to bound the measure of $ \{ \gamma \in [0,1]: |P t - \gamma | < \epsilon  \} $, and then integrate that over $I$...

Comment: doesn't that cover all of $X(P)$? (surely I am missing something...)

Comment: Yes it does, but where does this $\int_I\dots dt$ come from (rather than $\sum_{t\in I}\dots$)?

Comment: If $\inf I=a$ and $\sup I= b$ then $\mbox{meas}X(P)\le\mbox{meas}(Pa-\epsilon,Pb+\epsilon)=P\mbox{meas}(I)+2\epsilon$.